# Subdomains on a multidomain EV SSL

Tags: certificates, certificate-authority

I have a domain https://joshmurray.eu/ which has a Standard SSL certificate.

I also have two subdomains: `http://one.joshmurray.eu/` and `http://two.joshmurray.eu/`.

I wish to upgrade my SSL certificate to an EV certificate so I can acquire the 'green box'. I wish to have this green box on every page, therefore I need a Multidomain EV SSL certificate - due to Wildcard EV certificates not being available.

My question: are subdomains allowed to be added onto a Multidomain EV SSL?

Comment: this is a question you need to ask your certificate provider

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EV certificates can have several domains (including subdomains) inside the same certificate as can be easily seen when simply looking at existing EV. Take for example the EV certificate for www.paypal.com which is valid for:

```
history.paypal.com, t.paypal.com, c.paypal.com, c6.paypal.com, 
developer.paypal.com, p.paypal.com, www.paypal.com
```

Comment: Isn't it what OP called "Multidomain EV SSL" on the first place? How is it supposed to answer the question?

Comment: @techraf: since the OP explicitly asked for sub-domains I thought that OP assumed that multi-domain is for distinct domains (example.com, example.org) only and not for sub-domains. Otherwise I do not understand what this question is about at all. This example with paypal is what the OP asked for, i.e. several subdomains of the same domain.

Comment: I see it now. Confusing question.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich: I was wondering if multi-domain included sub-domains and not only 'distinct' domains. Thank you.

Comment: @JoshMurray: multi-domain includes whatever the CA allows you to include and might differ between the CA's. In theory a certificate can include different domains, sub-domains, wildcards, ... all at the same time but not all CA allow you to do this.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich: Ahh right, I shall contact the CA and see what they say. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Technically speaking it is impossible to "add" a SAN to an existing certificate, because the new certificate will differ from the old one. They can share other details like CN, organization, expiration date.

When you want to add domains, you issue a new Certificate Signing Request and send it to your certification authority for signing.

[Here's](https://www.digicert.com/uc-certificate-add-subject-alternative-names.htm) how the process works for one of them, however particular conditions for issuing new certificate depend on certificate authority.