# EV SSL on top level, and other SSL on subdomain

Tags: tls

I am the CTO for a new Startup SAAS that will be handling financial information.  We are considering purchasing a EV SSL, but our application is planned to run on a sub domain like app.ourdomain.com.   It seems like many EV SSL certs seem to indicate they only cover the Top Level domain  of www.our-domain.com or our-domain.com, so as such would provide no benefit for actual the application (customer dashboard) on the "app." subdomain.

We would like to use the app subdomain because of the freedom to have the application running on a different physical or virtual server, but it is actually this server that would be handling the actual financial service.  Am I missing something on applying a EV SSL to the sub-domain?  I see in this thread that the accepted answer indicates a EV can apply to subdomain [Subdomains on a multidomain EV SSL](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/118932/subdomains-on-a-multidomain-ev-ssl).  However this is not how most EV certificate descriptions actually read.  What is the best way to handle a SSLs for a domain structure like ours?

Comment: *However this is not how most EV certificate descriptions actually read.* - what does it matter what *most* provide as long as they are vendors of multi-domain certificates  (if your unproven statement is true at all). There are [easy to find](https://www.google.com/search?q=multi-domain+ev+ssl) vendors of multi-domain EV certificates, for example [Entrust](https://www.entrust.com/ev-multi-domain-ssl-certificates/)
 or [Comodo](https://www.namecheap.com/security/ssl-certificates/comodo/ev-multi-domain.aspx).

Comment: Oh, you are correct the Comodo EV multi domain on Namecheap does indicate it can be applied to a sub domain.  The wording on the single EV SSL though would lead some to believe it only secures a top level.  https://www.namecheap.com/security/ssl-certificates/comodo/ev.aspx

Comment: Yes, the offered single domain EV certificate *"Secures www.site.com and site.com"* as cited from the description. If you want more you need a multi-domain EV certificate and have to include this requirement in your search.